# How can I access gnuplot's options?

Tags: 16.04, gnuplot

I've installed gnuplot on Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm confused on how to access the options. A plot looks of, for instance, sin(x) and cos(x) looks now like this[image]

But on Ubuntu 14.04 it looked more like this[image]

On Ubuntu 16.04 it appears as if the options have disappeared (for instance if I would like to add a grid). Does anybody know how I can access them?

Comment: Difference between the `gnuplot-x11` and `gnuplot-qt` packages?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes you're right, thank you!! If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Please add always the version of gnuplot that you are using, and in this case the type of the terminal too (you can see it with ` print GNUTERM  ` inside gnuplot CLI, _command line interface)_: it will make your question (and the answer) useful for a broader audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first image looks like the regular (with `wxt` terminal type) output from the X11 version of GNUplot, provided on Ubuntu by the `gnuplot-x11` package.

In order to get the interactive chart window, you need to use the Qt version of GNUplot, provided by package `gnuplot-qt`.